# Order grid in Bootstrap Vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, css-grid

A data is fetched from an API and it'll be rendered each one in a div, by a v-for loop. And I want the grid of divs to be like this:

```
[-- item 1 --][-- item-2 --]
[-- item 3 --][-- item-4 --]
[-- item 5 --][-- item-6 --]
[-- item 7 --][-- item-8 --]
```

But I can't figure it out yet how to do it in Bootstrap or Vue or CSS.

Comment: Convert the data array into two computed property arrays, one containing the odd index elements and the other containing the even.  The create two v-for elements side by side.

Comment: just place `class="col-6"` on the div

Answer (score 0):

Better to implement such things using the [Layout and Grid System of Bootstrap](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/layout).

Pay attention to the attribute `cols=""` of the `<b-col>` ([doc](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/layout#grid-options))

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
        {name: 1},
        {name: 2},
        {name: 3},
        {name: 4},
        {name: 5},
        {name: 6},
        {name: 7},
        {name: 8},
    ]
  }
})
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="app">
  <b-container>
    <b-row>
      <b-col 
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item.name"
        cols="6"
      >
        Item {{ item.name }}
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</div>
```